# Why the number of the vertices is even?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $V$ the vertex set. Suppose that for each non-empty subset $W$ of $V$ there exists an element $\omega \in V$ ( maybe in $W$ or not) such that the degree of $\omega$ in $W$ is odd ( that is, there are odd vertices in $W$ which connected to  $\omega$  ), then we can make a conclusion that $n$ is even.

Comment: Let A be the adjacency matrix (with 0's on the diagonal). A counterexample would be when n is odd and W is encoded by a binary vector w such that Aw = 0 (mod 2). So it suffices to show that any adjacency matrix of odd size is singular mod 2.

Comment: A symmetric binary matrix has even rank over GF(2). So any graph with an odd number of vertices has a vector w in the null space of its adjacency matrix. This vector is the characteristic vector of a set W that violates the condition of the theorem (as in Erik's comment).

Comment: Oops, forgot to say "with zero diagonal" in the first sentence.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: If it's a homework why no people can solve it? I think, it would not be a simple question by using an elementary method. I hope someone put forward a method. Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: @Benjamin Young：I do this problem just for my interest not a homework. Someone tell me this problem and I changed it into the language of graph theory.